# How to use levels instead of labels in creating conditionals R

Tags: r

I want to know how to use the levels in stead of the labels in R

Before, I have utilized the following code

```
df2 <- df %>%
  filter(type_A == 1 | (type_B == 2 & explanation == 3))
```

At a certain point I have factorized the variables and provided labels to the levels. For example

1 = XXX, 2 = YYY, 3 = ZZZ

Now when I use the code above, it does not work. It report 0 values.

I have to change it to:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  filter(type_A == "XXX" | (type_B == "YYY" & explanation == "ZZZ"))
```

This would however require more typing and I would need to change the already written code in it's entirety.

How could I solve this?

Comment: `as.numeric` converts a factor to its levels. You could use `filter(as.numeric(type_A) == 1 | (as.numeric(type_B) == 2 ...)`... that's pretty bad too. I think you should pick a paradigm and stick with it. Working in both will be tough. (Or keep an  integer version and a labeled version of the column, and use whichever is appropriate)

Comment: thank you, it's a pity R could not automatically recognise the correct input